# How to fix "NameError: uninitialized constant Thor::Base" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, thor

I am in the process of developing a Rails Engine (currently using Rails 4.1.6). I get this error when I try to run any Rake tasks:

```
$ bundle exec rake app:db:migrate --trace
** Invoke load_app (first_time)
** Execute load_app
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Thor::Base
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:12:in `initialize'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:26:in `new'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:13:in `new'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:13:in `install_tasks'
/Users/andrew/example_rails_engine/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

My Rakefile is as follows:

```
begin
  require 'bundler/setup'
rescue LoadError
  puts 'You must `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` to run rake tasks'
end

APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../spec/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)
load 'rails/tasks/engine.rake'

Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks
```

This error doesn't make sense to me. I'm guessing Thor is a dependency of Rails Rake tasks. Where is this error coming from and how do I fix it?

Comment: `thor` is the gem that rails generators are written in. But I don't really understand what's going on. If I create an engine myself with `rails plugin new some_engine`, I can successfully run `bundle exec rake app:db:migrate` on it.  Perhaps some other code you've added but not shown us is triggering the problem -- although the stack trace doesn't really give us much of a clue in that direction. Hm, mysterious. I wonder if you have somehow have incompatible versions of gems in use; I'd run a `bundle update` just to be sure you have latest version of all gems, but I suspect that won't help.

Comment: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2901 - maybe related...

Comment: Either do what @jrochkind suggested, or try adding the `thor` gem to the `Gemfile`.

Comment: what Brad said, it sounds an awful lot like that bundler bug, I'd go report it there. Nice find Brad.

Comment: That GitHub issue does not provide a resolution. However, my Gemfile lists `guard` as a dependency. When I removed it, I was able to run `rake`. It seems like maybe Guard's version of Thor is conflicting with Bundler's version of Thor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with either:

- Bundler: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3205
- or guard-rspec: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/258

Guard lists Thor as a dependency, while Bundler vendors its own version of Thor, causing some sort of conflict.

I was able to temprorarily fix the problem by changing the order in which the code is loaded:

Move this line: `Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks` above these lines:

```
APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../spec/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)
load 'rails/tasks/engine.rake'
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
 require 'thor'
```

to your `RakeFile` before

```
 Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks
```

fixed the issue for me